Skip python cell execution in Jupyter notebooks
Is there a way to mark a python code block in Jupyter notebooks so that it does not run? Unmark it and it runs? Having to comment out every line of code in a block is time consuming.
Thank you in advance for the help with this.
I have searched the web for solutions and read about converting the block to raw and have seen other scripts and magics but the feedback is they work for Unix but windows throws errors.

How would switching a cell to raw only work in Unix?

if run_cell:, perhaps?

Place the code in the block behind an if statement with a guard variable or use multi-line comments. Though, this suggests to me that you might be using this notebook in a production workflow and that is an anti-pattern IMHO.

Have you seen %%script echo skipping suggested in a reply to 'Is there a cell tag convention to skip execution?' and in the reference therein.

Thanks for the feedback. I am running in windows. I will give the if statement a try. My code blocks carry out various drops  in the data set that one might want to see results for. It could be convenient if there were a "do not run" designation that allows for running " all above" in the notebook instead of running block by block to avoid running all the drops.
